# How to extract PowerShell results to DataTable in vb.net

Tags: powershell, psobject

I would like to extract the PowerShell output and extract the data and store in DataTable in VB.NET, I want to display the output in a GridView
I need extract the column and value from the PowerShell output in VB.NET

***Here is the PowerShell:***

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -NotLike '*Windows Server*'} -Property * | 
select Name, operatingSystem, LastLogonDate, Description, whenChanged | 
Where {($_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)) -and ($_.LastLogonDate -ne $NULL)}
```

***Here is the PowerShell result:***

```
Name            : PCO37
operatingSystem : Windows 7 Professional
LastLogonDate   : 1/13/2020 10:04:23 AM
Description     :
whenChanged     : 1/17/2020 1:22:08 PM

Name            : PCO41
operatingSystem : Windows 7 Professional
LastLogonDate   : 2/10/2019 4:43:31 PM
Description     :
whenChanged     : 2/10/2019 4:47:05 PM

Name            : PCO40
operatingSystem : Windows 7 Professional
LastLogonDate   : 4/8/2019 10:03:38 PM
Description     :
whenChanged     : 4/11/2019 6:29:25 AM

Name            : PCO09
operatingSystem : Windows 7 Professional
LastLogonDate   : 3/6/2019 8:04:59 AM
Description     :
whenChanged     : 3/6/2019 8:09:39 AM
```

***Here is my code in VB.NET:***

```
Function PSObjectToDataTable(ByVal command As String) As DataTable

    ' Initialize PowerShell engine
    Dim Ps As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()

    ' add the script the PowerShell command
    Ps.Commands.AddScript(command)

    ' Execute the script
    Dim results = Ps.Invoke()

    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("Detail")
    Dim Name As String
    Dim CanonicalName As String
    For Each psObject As PSObject In results
        dt.Rows.Add(psObject.ToString)
    Next

    Return dt

End Function
```

***Here is the result of the VB.NET:***

```
Detail
@{Name=PC037; operatingSystem=Windows 7 Professional; LastLogonDate=1/13/2020 10:04:23 AM; Description=; whenChanged=1/17/2020 1:22:08 PM}   
@{Name=PC041;  operatingSystem=Windows 7 Professional; LastLogonDate=2/10/2019 4:43:31 PM; Description=; whenChanged=2/10/2019 4:47:05 PM}   
@{Name=PC040; operatingSystem=Windows 7 Professional; LastLogonDate=4/8/2019 10:03:38 PM; Description=; whenChanged=4/11/2019 6:29:25 AM}    
@{Name=PC009;  operatingSystem=Windows 7 Professional; LastLogonDate=3/6/2019 8:04:59 AM; Description=; whenChanged=3/6/2019 8:09:39 AM}
```

Comment: If you're looking to convert an array of PSObject to .Net's DataTable type, take a look at `ConvertTo-DataTable`, defined here: https://powersnippets.com/convertto-datatable/.  If you need to interact with VB.Net, please can you share the VB.Net code used to invoke PowerShell, or describe a bit more about the interaction between the two languages?

Comment: You might also take a look at this idea: [`#11987` Extend **DataTable** with easy constructor and AddRow method](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11987)

Comment: I need a code to extract the data from PowerShell output to VB.NET, i dont need the DataTable inside PowerShell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the answer by myself.

To extract the properties from the PowerShell Object, i have to specific the item name, **cannot use the index of the PowerShell Object property.**

***## Correct Syntax ##***

```
psObject.Properties("Name").Value.ToString
psObject.Properties("CanonicalName").Value.ToString
psObject.Properties("operatingSystem").Value.ToString
psObject.Properties("LastLogonDate").Value.ToString
psObject.Properties("whenChanged").Value.ToString
psObject.Properties("Description").Value.ToString
```

***## Wrong Syntax ##***

```
psObject.Properties(0).Value.ToString
psObject.Properties(1).Value.ToString
psObject.Properties(2).Value.ToString
psObject.Properties(3).Value.ToString
psObject.Properties(4).Value.ToString
psObject.Properties(5).Value.ToString
```

***Here is the code (dynamic create the column in Function: PSObjectToDataTable):***

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim func As New clsFunction
    Dim command As String = "Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -NotLike '*Windows Server*'} -Property * | select Name, CanonicalName, operatingSystem, LastLogonDate, Description, whenChanged | Where {($_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)) -and ($_.LastLogonDate -ne $NULL)}"

    Dim arr As New ArrayList
    arr.Add("Name")
    arr.Add("CanonicalName")
    arr.Add("operatingSystem")
    arr.Add("LastLogonDate")
    arr.Add("whenChanged")
    arr.Add("Description")

    Me.GridView1.DataSource = func.PSObjectToDataTable(command, arr)
    Me.GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub

Function PSObjectToDataTable(ByVal command As String, ByVal arr As ArrayList) As DataTable

    ' Initialize PowerShell engine
    Dim Ps As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()

    ' add the script the PowerShell command
    Ps.Commands.AddScript(command)

    ' Execute the script
    Dim results = Ps.Invoke()

    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim dr As DataRow = Nothing

    'Dynamic create cloumn
    For i = 0 To arr.Count - 1
        dt.Columns.Add(arr(i))
    Next

    For Each psObject As PSObject In results

        'Assign value to dynamic column
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        For i = 0 To arr.Count - 1

            'Check if object is null
            If psObject.Properties(arr(i)).Value Is Nothing Then
                dr(i) = ""
            Else
                dr(i) = psObject.Properties(arr(i)).Value.ToString
            End If

        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next

    Return dt

End Function
```

Comment: i am working on a lib wrapping all this stuff for you. i will open source it in the next days.

Comment: @Bhaal22 - did you ever do the lib you mentioned ?

Comment: @DarrenRose excellent reminder ! i had too much to do in the last months but I will work on it. It's almost there.

Comment: @Bhaal22 - excellent - look forward to hearing more in due course

Answer (score 0):

I figured I would shoot an example in here as well.  I tried making it as dynamic as possible including field types. Int32 String etc..
Be gentle it is my first time posting in here.

```
Imports System.Management.Automation

Function PSObjectToDataTable(ByVal command As String) As DataTable

        ' Initialize PowerShell engine
        Dim Ps As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()

        ' add the script the PowerShell command
        Ps.Commands.AddScript(command)

        ' Execute the script
        Dim results = Ps.Invoke()
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        For Each psObject As PSObject In results
            If x = 0 Then
                For Each prop As PSPropertyInfo In psObject.Properties
                    dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value.GetType)
                Next
            End If
            Dim dtrow As DataRow
            dtrow = dt.NewRow
                For Each prop As PSPropertyInfo In psObject.Properties
                    Try
                        dtrow(prop.Name) = prop.Value
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        'do some debugging in here if you want to
                    End Try
                Next
                dt.Rows.Add(dtrow)
            x = x + 1
        Next
        Return dt

End Function
```